# Converting and mapping categorical data

Tags: python

I have a dataset which has categoric and numeric columns. I want to convert the categoric data to numeric together with mapping each type of category to a specific numeric value. For example, under column ['Education'], I have Highschool, Undergraduate, Graduate, PHD etc. I'd appreciate if someone could provide me the code to map each code to an arbitrary numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["Highschool", "Undergraduate","Highschool" ,"Graduate", "PHD", "Graduate", "Graduate","Undergraduate"],columns = ["Education"]) 
df_transformed = pd.get_dummies(df)

df_transformed.head()
```

OP:

```
 Education_Graduate Education_Highschool    Education_PHD   Education_Undergraduate
0         0               1                    0                0
1         0               0                    0                1
2         0               1                    0                0
3         1               0                    0                0
4         0               0                    1                0
```

#Label Encoding

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(df["Education"].values)

#use_any_input_list_here and it will assign a numerical value. I have given a sample list
encoder.transform(["Undergraduate","Highschool" ,"Graduate"])
```

Comment: Thanks that is useful but I was looking for a way to use cat.codes function in order to group the data.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want, I dont understand.

Comment: For example, I'd want to assign Graduate to 1, Highschool to 2, PHD to 3 and so on. maintaining one column only for education levels but just having them in numeric values instead of categorical values. Hope I was clear enough